# The Google AppEngine Cloud SQL Java example code has errors... how can I get it to work?

Tags: java, mysql, google-app-engine, jdbc

I'm trying to get Google Cloud SQL working with AppEngine using Java. I followed the example here https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/cloud-sql/?csw=1#using_the_java_development_server but there seem to be errors (or at least omissions) in the code.

The line `Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);` shows an error because there is no such class as `com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.DriverManager`, and the connection created by `com.google.cloud.sql.jdbc.Connection` is of a different type than the one needed by `java.sql.DriverManager`.

The example does not show what imports they used, and I can't find a set of imports that work properly.

I actually did get the example to work deployed in Google AppEngine, but can't get it to also work locally, and the deployed version is VERY SLOW, perhaps because I got it to work by using the `java.sql` classes rather than the `com.google.cloud.sql` classes (since there doesn't appear to be a complete set of the latter).

I know this can't be too complicated, but I have been unable to figure it out for 2 full days. If you know how to get this to work or what silly thing I am missing, please let me know.